# How can I call a line from the top left corner to bottom right corner of a non-square matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I'm programming attention penalty masks, which const of either square or non-square matrices, for adding bigger penalties on the attention weights of more distant position-pairs.

If the matrix is square, then I can easily say weights on diagonal get the smallest penalty.
But for the non-square matrix, I just wonder how I call the line from top left to right bottom?

Comment: How about the "diagonal"?

Comment: I confused since the matrix's main diagonal consists of the elements on "i=j".
But in this case, mostly "i" is not equal to "j". If there is no such a term then I can just call it the diagonal of non-square matrices. Thanks.